# click event on a link doesn't work in jquery

Tags: jquery, events, click

if element has class user i need to click on a link.
the alert executes but link don't work.

```
function gotoproduct()
{
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if($(this).hasClass("user"))
    {
        alert(""); // alert works.
    $('#mainnavi li a[title = "users"]').click(); // it's not working
    }
    else
    {
    window.location.replace("../"+tab+"/product.php?subjectid="+id+"");
    }
}
```

html:

```
<div id="mainnavi" title="">
<ul style="margin-top:10px;">
<li><a title="phones" href="../phones/firstpage.php" >گوشی</a></li>
<li><a title="users" href="../users/firstpage.php" >گوشی</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `$(this)` here?

Comment: it's a div, as i mentioned alert works.

Comment: Did you try `.trigger('click')`?

Comment: .trigger didn't work @flix

Comment: see demo : http://jsfiddle.net/a6NJk/647/

Comment: please explain more @AwladLiton, what was that? what should i do!?

Comment: my connection is slow, it has been just loaded. let me see again

Comment: i didn't write a function for link, i just want to load href attribute on click! @Awladliton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 $('#mainnavi li a[title = "users"]').get(0).click();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a6NJk/652/
try to see request by debugging. it is redirecting :)

there is another  alternative way you can do this

like this:

```
if($(this).hasClass("user"))
    {
     alert(""); // alert works.
      window.location.href = $('#mainnavi li a[title = "users"]').attr("href"); 
    }
```

sample demo : http://jsfiddle.net/a6NJk/651/

```
 function doclicking(){
         var link = $('#mainnavi li a[title = "users"]').attr("href");
         window.location.href= link;       
     } 
     doclicking();
```